# Can I change a private readonly inherited field in C# using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, superclass

like in java I have:

```
Class.getSuperClass().getDeclaredFields()
```

how I can know and set private field from a superclass?

I know this is strongly not recommended, but I am testing my application and I need simulate a wrong situation where the id is correct and the name not. But this Id is private.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use reflection to set the value of a readonly field after the constructor has run

```
var fi = this.GetType()
             .BaseType
             .GetField("_someField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

fi.SetValue(this, 1);
```

**EDIT**

Updated to look in the direct parent type.  This solution will likely have issues if the types are generic.

Comment: u now why I only can get my field using "<Id>k__BackingField"?

Answer (score 1):

This class will let you do it:

http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Reflection/PropertyType.cs

Usage:

```
new PropertyType(this.GetType(), "_myParentField").SetValue(this, newValue);
```

BTW, It will work on public/non-public fields or properties.  For ease of use you can use the derived class [PropertyValue](http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Reflection/PropertyValue.cs) like this:

```
new PropertyValue<int>(this,  "_myParentField").Value = newValue;
```

Comment: +1 for the csharptest-net library.  It has an interesting logger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

For fields, use the `FieldInfo` class.  The `BindingFlags.NonPublic` parameter allows you to see private fields.

```
public class Base
{
    private string _id = "hi";

    public string Id { get { return _id; } }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public void changeParentVariable()
    {
        FieldInfo fld = typeof(Base).GetField("_id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        fld.SetValue(this, "sup");
    }
}
```

and a small test to prove it works:

```
public static void Run()
{
    var derived = new Derived();
    Console.WriteLine(derived.Id); // prints "hi"
    derived.changeParentVariable();
    Console.WriteLine(derived.Id); // prints "sup"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like JaredPar suggests, I did the follow:

```
//to discover the object type
Type groupType = _group.GetType();
//to discover the parent object type
Type bType = groupType.BaseType;
//now I get all field to make sure that I can retrieve the field.
FieldInfo[] idFromBaseType = bType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

//And finally I set the values. (for me, the ID is the first element)
idFromBaseType[0].SetValue(_group, 1);
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Are you sure that idFromBaseType[0] is the correct field? You probably should match by name...

Comment: For me works, cause my first element is the ID. 
But I have tried get the field with string however with no success.