# Xamarin - Radial Progress Component Issue

Tags: android, xamarin

I 've been trying to implement the RadialProgress component (https://components.xamarin.com/view/radialprogress) on my app.
I managed to get it on the screen, and change the progress colour but I can't find a way to change the inner colour of the circle.

The RadialProgressView object itself has a BackgroundTintMode field which takes a DuffPorter.Mode but whenever I try to set the background tint mode the app breaks with this message (Message = "no method with name='setBackgroundTintMode' signature='(Landroid/graphics/PorterDuff$Mode;))

Is there even a way to do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: u got any solution for that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't Sarath. I haven't tried Mina's suggestion yet though so when I do I 'll let you know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Although not in a very straight-forward way or even  maintainable way.

Firstly, let's dig a little into `RadialProgressView`'s drawing code (as exposed by Xamarin Studio Assembly Browser):

```
    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // ... there's more stuff here, but you get the idea
        canvas.DrawCircle(this.bgCx, this.bgCy, this.radius, this.bgCirclePaint);
        canvas.DrawCircle(this.bgCx, this.bgCy, this.innerLineRadius, this.bgBorderPaint);
        canvas.DrawText(this.valueText, this.textX, this.textY, this.textPaint);
    }
```

We notice some colors here, like `bgCirclePaint`and `bgBorderPaint`. If we are able to change the value of these variables, we will be able to change the color with which the ProgressView is painted.

The problem is that `RadialProgressView` does not expose the fields – they are all private, so simply inheriting from `RadialProgressView` will not allow us to set them to a new value.

However, we can make use of [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401458/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-inherited-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection) to change these private fields, like so:

```
        var textPaintMember = typeof(RadialProgressView).GetField("textPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        textPaintMember.SetValue(Instance, MyNewSuperCoolColorPaint);
```

By combining the two, we can come up with a new, customizable class like this:

```
public class CustomizableRadialProgressView : RadialProgressView 
{
    public CustomizableRadialProgressView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public void SetTextColor(Color color) 
    {
        var paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetTypeface(Typeface.DefaultBold); 
        paint.Color = color;
        paint.AntiAlias = true;

        var textPaintMember = typeof(RadialProgressView).GetField("textPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        textPaintMember.SetValue(this, paint);
    }

    public void SetCircleColor(Color color) 
    {
        var paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        paint.Color = color;
        paint.AntiAlias = true;

        var circlePaintMember = typeof(RadialProgressView).GetField("bgCirclePaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        circlePaintMember.SetValue(this, paint);
    }

    public void SetBorderColor(Color color) 
    {
        var paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.Color = color;
        paint.AntiAlias = true;

        var circlePaintMember = typeof(RadialProgressView).GetField("bgBorderPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        circlePaintMember.SetValue(this, paint);
    }


    public void SetProgressPackgroundColor(Color color) 
    {
        var paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.Color = color;
        paint.AntiAlias = true;

        var circlePaintMember = typeof(RadialProgressView).GetField("bgProgressPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        circlePaintMember.SetValue(this, paint);
    }
}
```

This will get us the result we're after:

[image: 2]

Note: It is probably wise to notice that we are making improper use of private fields: We're manipulating them from outside of the class they live in. If Xamarin ever decides to change the way `RadialProgressView`is implemented, or even only renames one of the private variables, our code will fail at runtime. The better way to approach this problem would probably be to just ask Xamarin to provide the getters/setters you need. But, hey, it's SO much cooler this way ;)

Comment: can we change only center part of the ring ?

Comment: @SarathiOS: I'm not sure I understand your question. Which part would you like to change, too?

Comment: the view around that Label (40) that view i have to change. Is it possible ?

Comment: @SarathiOS: I've added two more color setters. Basically, you need to set the BorderColor back to anything that you'd like, and also the ProgressBackgroundColor. So by setting all four colors to new values it's possible. There's one limitation: at the very outside of the circle you'll get a very slim (1px?) border of the CircleColor, under any circumstances. So it would be best to pick colors that hide this this, like I did.

Comment: Thaks for you time and reply

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing a custom ViewRenderer and access the underlying native Android views to modify them as you want.
https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin.forms-on-android/

The error you have regarding the "setBackgroundTintMode" method indicates that you may need to update your Xamarin platform to make sure that the latest APIs are available

Comment: i have implemented this radial Progress View in my ios App. But unfortunately i didn't find any option to change its background. Inner area. I have to Change its background to White

Comment: You have any idea to change the back ground of Radial Progress view. Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you have to access the underlying components and change their properties, in Android if you can cast the RadialProgressView to a ViewGroup, you can access the children via getChildAt(int index) method.

Comment: @SARATH Can you please post your iOS solution?

Comment: @Lijo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693428/drawing-circles-in-xamarin-ios-xamarin-monotouch-for-showing-progress-graphica you can use this solution