# Drawing Circles In Xamarin.iOS (Xamarin Monotouch) for Showing Progress Graphically

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

As I'm very new to **Xamarin** World and new to its controls. I would like to add Circles to Show Work Progress in my mono touch app. For showing Progress I have to mark an Arc in the circle. And if possible any one can help with me a sample code. Awaiting an answer, Thanks a lot in advance.[image: i like to add image like this with two text filed init]

Comment: I see that you're quite familiar with iOS as such. Is your question about the Xamarin aspects of it? Basically, you can just do the same in Xamarin.iOS as in Objective-C-iOS (i.e. create a UIView, load some UIImages add a UILabel, rotate the image, etc.).

Comment: @FelixAlcala Thanks For your reply. And i got solution for that.(A User Interface Component) Made by Xamarin

Comment: Ah, interesting. What's the name of the component?

Comment: @FelixAlcala https://components.xamarin.com/view/radialprogress

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Result of the view]

```
using System;
    using UIKit;
    using CoreGraphics;

    namespace CircleTest.Touch
    {
        public class CircleGraph : UIView
        {
            int _radius = 10;
            int _lineWidth = 10;
            nfloat _degrees = 0.0f;
            UIColor _backColor = UIColor.FromRGB(46, 60, 76);
            UIColor _frontColor = UIColor.FromRGB(234, 105, 92);
            //FromRGB (234, 105, 92);

        public CircleGraph (CGRect frame, int lineWidth, nfloat degrees)
        {
            _lineWidth = lineWidth; 
            _degrees = degrees; 
            this.Frame = new CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height);
            this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear; 

        }

        public CircleGraph (CGRect frame, int lineWidth, UIColor backColor, UIColor frontColor)
        {
            _lineWidth = lineWidth;
            this.Frame = new CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height);
            this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

        }

        public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw (rect);

            using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ()) {
                _radius = (int)( (this.Bounds.Width) / 3) - 8;
                DrawGraph(g, this.Bounds.GetMidX(), this.Bounds.GetMidY());
            };
        }

        public void DrawGraph(CGContext g,nfloat x0,nfloat y0) {
            g.SetLineWidth (_lineWidth);

            // Draw background circle
            CGPath path = new CGPath ();
            _backColor.SetStroke ();
            path.AddArc (x0, y0, _radius, 0, 2.0f * (float)Math.PI, true);
            g.AddPath (path);
            g.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);

            // Draw overlay circle
            var pathStatus = new CGPath ();
            _frontColor.SetStroke ();
            pathStatus.AddArc(x0, y0, _radius, 0, _degrees * (float)Math.PI, false);
            g.AddPath (pathStatus);
            g.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually this is what iam actually supposed to do. Its working for me

This is how it look like. U can create it like a class file and simply u can assign to a UIView. 
For more reference you can use this sample project [Pi Graph](https://github.com/sarathdev/Circle-Di-Graph)

**[EDIT]:** *The `Draw` method originally passed the `View.Frame` x,y to the `DrawGraph` method. This should be `View.Bounds` (modified above to reflect this). Remember that the frame x,y is in reference to the containing superview and bounds is referenced to the current view. This would have worked if the view was added at 0,0 but once you start moving around the UI it disappears. When the arcs are drawn the values for x,y passed to AddArc need to be in reference to the current view not the parent superview.*

Answer (score 11):

Drawing a circle on a GLContext isn't that hard to do and is the same as you would do in Objective-C or Swift.

I assume you want to create your own view which you can reuse. To do so, simply inherit from `UIView`:

```
public class CircleView : UIView
{
}
```

Now to draw anything in your new custom view you want to override the `Draw` method:

```
public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
    // draw stuff in here
}
```

To draw stuff you need to get hold of the current context from `UIGraphics`, which can be done like so:

```
using (var gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
{
    // use gctx to draw stuff
}
```

The `CGContext` you get back, is very similar to `Canvas` on Android for instance. It has helper methods to draw arcs, circles, rectangles, points and much more.

So to draw a simple circle in that context, you do:

```
gctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Cyan.CGColor);
gctx.AddEllipseInRect(rect);
```

So combine everything you get:

```
public class CircleView : UIView
{
    public override Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        using (var gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            gctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Cyan.CGColor);
            gctx.AddEllipseInRect(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

That is it! Well, not exactly, this is where you need to start think of how you want to draw your progress indicator. What I think would probably work is:

1. Draw the back ground
2. Draw the borders
3. Calculate the degrees from the progress in percent
4. Use the degrees to create an arc using `gctx.AddArc()`, which can take an angle and draw an arc.
5. Draw the percentage as a string in the middle

To draw a string you will need to convert your string to a `NSAttributedString` then use `CTLine` to draw the text like:

```
using(var line = new CTLine(nsAttrString))
    line.Draw(gctx);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. But i have implemented it using a component called "Radial Progress" from xamarin. Thanks again

Comment: @Cheesbaron you know how to change the background color of "Radial Progress" view?

Comment: By the way, in the example of @Cheesebaron, you should use FillEllipseInRect instead of AddEllipseInRect... And add BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
in the constructor of you UIView derivate... I've been stuck for an hour with that... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Minor alterations to the answer provided by @SARATH as copying and pasting did not yield the desired result.

Changed _degrees to _percentComplete

Fixed overload constructor for changing colors by adding a param for percentComplete and added missing member variable assignments for _backColor and _frontColor

Added constant float value for drawing a full circle (FULL_CIRCLE)

Multiply _percentComplete by FULL_CIRCLE to get the end angle for both arcs (with different directions)

Calculation of the radius

```
  public class CircleGraph : UIView
  {
      const float FULL_CIRCLE = 2 * (float)Math.PI;
      int _radius = 10;
      int _lineWidth = 10;
      nfloat _percentComplete = 0.0f;
      UIColor _backColor = UIColor.LightGray; //UIColor.FromRGB(46, 60, 76);
      UIColor _frontColor = UIColor.Green; //UIColor.FromRGB(234, 105, 92);

      public CircleGraph(CGRect frame, int lineWidth, nfloat percentComplete)
      {
         _lineWidth = lineWidth;
         _percentComplete = percentComplete;
         this.Frame = new CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height);
         this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

      }

      public CircleGraph(CGRect frame, int lineWidth, nfloat percentComplete, UIColor backColor, UIColor frontColor)
      {
         _lineWidth = lineWidth;
         _percentComplete = percentComplete;
         this.Frame = new CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height);
         this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
         _backColor = backColor;
         _frontColor = frontColor;
      }

      public override void Draw(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
      {
         base.Draw(rect);

         using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
         {
            var diameter = Math.Min(this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);
            _radius = (int)(diameter / 2) - _lineWidth;

            DrawGraph(g, this.Bounds.GetMidX(), this.Bounds.GetMidY());
         };
      }

      public void DrawGraph(CGContext g, nfloat x, nfloat y)
      {
         g.SetLineWidth(_lineWidth);

         // Draw background circle
         CGPath path = new CGPath();
         _backColor.SetStroke();
         path.AddArc(x, y, _radius, 0, _percentComplete * FULL_CIRCLE, true);
         g.AddPath(path);
         g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);

         // Draw overlay circle
         var pathStatus = new CGPath();
         _frontColor.SetStroke();

         // Same Arc params except direction so colors don't overlap
         pathStatus.AddArc(x, y, _radius, 0, _percentComplete * FULL_CIRCLE, false);
         g.AddPath(pathStatus);
         g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);
      }
   }
```

**Example**

```
var circleGraph = new CircleGraph(circleGraphView.Frame, 20, 0.75f);
```

*CircleGraph at 75%*

[image: CircleGraph displaying 75%]

Comment: How to make it interactive ? Means i want to make a video recorder button in which green colour part will fill along with the video parallelly.

Comment: Sorry I did not find a way to animate the graph

Comment: @mjwheat It worked for me but I want to start from top not from the right side. I tried to rotate CGContext to 270/-90 degrees. but it always start from right side. I also tried to change startangle to 270 but it didn't affect also. can you pls help ?

Comment: @Monica when you said you tried changing the startangle were you referring to this line `path.AddArc(x, y, _radius, 0, _percentComplete * FULL_CIRCLE, true);
         g.AddPath(path);`  The 0 is the start angle and next arg is the end angle.  Have you tried modifying those two values?

Comment: Yes, i tried to change direction too.. but it doesn't affect.

Comment: What happens if you change the x and y args passed to DrawGraph()? `DrawGraph(g, this.Bounds.GetMidX(), this.Bounds.GetMidY());`

Comment: what should I add to x,y args ? I tried to add left, top but it doesn't work