# error CS0133: Assigning the result of a function to a const in C#.net

Tags: c#, syntax, pinvoke

Trying to tidy up scope and avoid possible multiple calls to RegisterWindowMessage.
Currently have a class used once with the following member

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

private int m_message = RegisterWindowMessage("MY_MSG");
```

As we only have one instance this seems ok, but think it would be more tidy to use.  With my basic C# understanding this should call RegisterWindowMessage and assign the result to int and not allow it to change.

```
private const int message = RegisterWindowMessage("MY_MSG");
```

however attempting to do so leads to a

```
error CS0133: The expression being assigned to 'someclass.messageEvent' must be constant
```

so now I'm confused, does this mean the function was being assigned and called each time `m_message` was used previously, is there something else missing?

Comment: See [What is the difference between const and readonly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `const` field has to be a *compile-time constant*. If you just want something which won't change at execution time after initial assignment<sup>1</sup>, make it readonly:

```
private static readonly int Message = RegisterWindowMessage("MY_MSG");
```

Note that I've made this static, which `const` is implicitly. This means `RegisterWindowMessage` will only be called once for this AppDomain, which is what I think you want.

EDIT: Hans is right, you should check the return value. You could either do that when you first use it, or when the type is initialized - usually it's a bad idea for type initializers to throw exceptions, but you should see what the impact is.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, a static readonly field can be assigned in the declaration or in the static constructor; an instance readonly field can be assigned in the declaration or in any instance constructor. It *can* be assigned multiple times, which is *usually* not useful, but can be just occasionally.

Comment: This is not okay, Windows API function calls must be checked for failure.

Answer (score 3):

There is another consideration here.  RegisterWindowMessage() can fail, you *really* need to check for that.  Using the 0 it returns when something is wrong is going to be horribly difficult to diagnose otherwise.

That knocks initializing it directly in the readonly declaration out.  You could use a static constructor instead.  Problem with that is that the exception message will be buried in an InnerException.  Kinda okay perhaps since failure will be rare.

The best solution is a static property getter that lazily calls the API:

```
private int m_message

public static int message {
  get {
    if (m_message == 0) {
      m_message = RegisterWindowMessage("blah");
      if (m_message == 0) throw new Win32Exception();
    }
    return m_message;
  }
}
```

Use well-known locking patterns if this might be called from different threads.

Comment: Thanks for this extra pointer on considering a possible error situation.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer that Hans gave, you can do better than simply throwing an empty Win32Exception. This applies to any API call that uses GetLastError:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
extern static int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

if (m_message == 0)
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

That will produce a more informative exception.

Comment: Hans is correct. I had to think about why I believed it to be not so.

If you do not specify SetLastError = true in the p/invoke declaration, the marshaller will not call GetLastError and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error will return 0 which causes the exception message to be, "The operation completed successfully".

By specifying Marshal.GetLastWin32Error in the Win32Exception constructor, you are essentially reminding yourself that you need to add SetLastError=true to the declaration.

Maybe I'm the only one who needs such a reminder.