# Is there any performance benefit in using const or readonly modifiers on fields in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, constants, readonly

Is there any performance benefit to using `const` or `readonly` fields compared to regular, modifiable fields, when only using private variables.

For example:

```
public class FooBaar
{
     private string foo = "something";
     private const string baar = "something more"

     public void Baaz()
     {
         //access foo, access baar
     }
}
```

In the above example you can see there are two fields: `foo` and `baar`. Both are unaccessible outside the the class, so how come many people prefer to use `const` here, instead of just `private`. Does the `const` provide any performance benefit?

---

This question was previously closed by the community, because people misunderstood this question as *"What is the difference between `const` and `readonly` in terms of performance?"*, which has been answered here: [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly).
But what I actually mean is, *"do I get any performance benefit by using `const` or `readonly` over not using any of them"*.

Comment: When you're bored with micro-optimization there's always nano-optimizing.

Comment: I have edited the question and would like ppl to see it!!

Comment: I think @spender already has the perfect answer to your edited question. Don't worry about speed here, try to be correct and obvious.

Comment: @Rusi Nova - your first string is not readonly it is private.  To make it readonly it should read 'private readonly string foo="something"'

Comment: @Henk - I (partially) disagree.  What should someone do when speed is an issue?  The question is about performance - the answer shouldn't just ignore that.  Spender's answer is perfectly good advice, but its not an answer to this question really.

Comment: If it's about performance the only sensible answer is: use a profiler to find the problem. Very unlikely to be (a missing) readonly or const.

Comment: @iandotkelly: i know its private, i deliberately made it private. Thats my question: do i get any performance benefit by using const(or readonly) over just private?? when my intention is just to create a string to be shared and used intrinsically by varios methods.

Comment: - different answers - const yes, readonly no

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about the performance of these constructs until you encounter a critical piece of code that requires you to make such measurements. They're there to ensure correctness of code, not for performance reasons.

Comment: Perfectly good advice, and I don't worry about performance either - but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question and assumes performance critical code is not being written.  It should definitely not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Daniel : experience has taught me that often, when the question is "which is faster, language feature X or language feature Y", the person is prioritizing the wrong investigation. "Performance benefits" can be easily measured by the OP and don't really represent a problem that should be asked on SO. Those who come looking for the answer to this question are best reminded that there is a good chance that they are probably looking at things with the wrong mindset.

Comment: That is not the question he asked, and whether or not the question should be here is not the issue.  If we have a bad question, must we also have a bad answer?  This answer would have been great as a comment, because that is what it is.  There is an actual, more informative answer just below, gathering dust.

Comment: @Daniel : True. Perhaps you could ping the OP to mark the other answer, then I'd happily demote this answer to a comment. Until then, "you cannot delete the accepted answer".

Comment: What's done is done.  It is a very old question.  I was just explaining my downvote as prompted by SO.

Answer (score 27):

A const will be optimized by the compiler to be inlined into your code, a readonly cannot be inlined.  However you cannot make constants of all types - so here you must make them readonly.

So if you need a constant value in your code, you should first look to use a const if possible, if not then readonly is there to allow you to have the safety, but not the performance benefits.

As an example:

```
public class Example
{
    private const int foo = 5;
    private readonly Dictionary<int, string> bar = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    //.... missing stuff where bar is populated

    public void DoSomething()
    {
       Console.Writeline(bar[foo]);

       // when compiled the above line is replaced with Console.Writeline(bar[5]);
       // because at compile time the compiler can replace foo with 5
       // but it can't do anything inline with bar itself, as it is readonly
       // not a const, so cannot benefit from the optimization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same and I've use a tool to check the resulting IL output from the use of static and read-only modifiers.

Check this example:

```
public class C {

    const string test = "stuff";
    private static string test2 = "stuff2";

    public static void M() {
        System.Console.WriteLine(test);
        System.Console.WriteLine(test2);
    }
}
```

And the IL output for M():

```
 IL_0000: nop
 IL_0001: ldstr "stuff"
 IL_0006: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
 IL_000b: nop
 IL_000c: ldsfld string C::test2
 IL_0011: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
 IL_0016: nop
 IL_0017: ret
```

It is unlikely that it will make any performance difference in current hardware, but it seems that constants will carry the data into the [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) when executing the instruction into the CPU, while the static reference will carry a memory pointer which will make the CPU retrieve the value in some register/L1 cache/so on.

Full output here: https://gist.github.com/VagnerGon/e8f48a652cc4f234c2ab060a5eeb7d2e

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I think it may have more relevance when working on WPF applications. I have multiple readonly properties in a custom class, and the DataTriggers in my XAML. So, in theory, every time my datasource (ItemsControl) updates it has to check every property. I haven't checked actual performance, but I imagine it has a negative effect on performance? If there is an option to set the value as a constant, would that be a better way?