# const vs. static readonly

Tags: c#, static, constants, readonly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

So from what I read, in C#, `const` and `static readonly` will both make a value unalterable during the execution of a program.

However, `const` should be used with quantities which are unlikely to ever change (e.g. pi, radius of earth, litters per gallon etc.).

On the other hand, `static readonly` should be used with values that currently are constant but might/will change in the future (e.g. software version, a multiplier in an algorithm etc.).

Have I got it right?

Comment: Actually this is rather the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const

I saw it before posting but it goes into depth before it explains it with simple English

Comment: That's a good link, especially the second answer with respect to the compilation differences between const and static readonly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know about your second item (I would probably use a constant for a software version or an algorithm… constant) but there is one key difference between the two: `const` can only hold basic types such as `string`, `bool`, or numeric types. `static readonly` can hold any object. So, for example, I often use `static readonly` to store resources like `Bitmap` objects. Those cannot be `const`.