# How Collections with Read Only Modifier became Modifiable in C#?

Tags: c#, collections

In the below code, Even though the collection is declared as `readonly`, we are able to add items into the collection. But it is a known fact like `readonly` modifier will allow initialization of the value either at declaration,initialization expression or in the constructor.
How the below is possible?
How `readonly` modifier behaves on different types?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadonlyStringHolder stringHolder = new ReadonlyStringHolder();
        stringHolder.Item = "Say Hello";//compile time error-Read only field cannot be initialized to

        ReadOnlyCollectionHolder collectionHolder = new ReadOnlyCollectionHolder();
        collectionHolder.ItemList.Add("A");
        collectionHolder.ItemList.Add("B");//No Error -How Is possible for modifying readonly collection

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ReadOnlyCollectionHolder
{
    public readonly IList<String> ItemList = new List<String>();
}
public class ReadonlyStringHolder
{
    public readonly String Item = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: the `IList` itself cannot be set. But nothing prevents you from calling methods on it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly

Comment: `readonly` is shallow - it applies to the field, not to whatever the field is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

[readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) doesn't allow just to change the instance (except in the constructor)

```
public class ReadOnlyCollectionHolder
{
    private List<string> _innerCollection=new List<string>();

    public ReadOnlyCollectionHolder()
    {
        ItemList = new ReadOnlyCollection<String> (_innerCollection);
    }

    public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<String> ItemList {get;private set;}
}
```

Comment: Basically, `readonly` changes the mutability of the variable itself (limiting it to just constructor can set the value) not the mutability of the backing object.

Comment: @Anthony I got it clear..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the ItemList instance but you can call its methods.
If you really want a readonly list you should consider using `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`