# Can't declare const field in class

Tags: c#

Please note that I'm not asking about the difference between *const*, *readonly* and *static*. I assumed that it was clear from the contents of the question but apparently I didn't succeed to make that clear enough.

I'm aware that when declaring a constant using the keyword *const*, I have to specify a value at compile time and that the value needs to be, well..., constant.

The following sample works but I found that a bit lengthy and unnecessarily relaxed, so I attempted to declare the field as *constant*. According to my estimation, we do have a constant specification of the contents and those are never changing.

```
static readonly List<int> Codes = new List<int> { 1337 };
```

Evidently, according to the computer it's not and the nit-picker won't compile the following example. That contradicts my expectations and I'm not clear on how the computer figures. Hence the question - why doesn't it like it?

```
const List<int> Codes = new List<int> { 1337 };
```

The exact formulation is, as one'd expect: *Constant initializer must be compile-time constant* but that answers *why the error*. It doesn't really explains *where's the non-constant part*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const and readonly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

Comment: @AlphaMCubed Care to point out **where** that link refers to my question? I can google "*const vs readonly*" too but it doesn't give me understanding for my confusion. Perhaps I'm just blinded by the unexpected.

Comment: From what I know, whatever is declared as constant, the compiler just replaces the reference to that variable with its value in place. I don't think this can be done for a List as the reference of the list will not change but the same is not true for the values in it.

Comment: @GaneshR. You should put that as a reply not comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` has to be `compile-time` constant. If you do `new Something()` that is not. See MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx).

But you can declare that as `static` as you have seen, which need not be a constant value.

Now, the field value has to be `compile-time-constant` means it's value must be known and constant at compile time itself. But when you call the `constructor` of a class, the actual object will be created at `run-time`, so that is not known for compiler.

Example:

```
const string Allowed = "hello!";
const string NotAllowed = new string(new char[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });
```

Comment: I'm not contradicting you. I just can't see how it's not constant - we have a memory allocation for the array, it's not going to change, it's not going to span over a larger or smaller chunk of the memory. How?! I'm too dense to see that... +1 for the lightning speed of the response.

Comment: Added some explanation and example, does that help you understand?

Comment: Yupp. Combined with the other comments/replies I see where my brains went poof. I can't accept your reply yet, though. Need to wait for a few minutes.

Comment: That's fine, wait accept the answer that helps you the most :)

Answer (score 3):

`const` has to be `compile-time` constant because its value will be **embeded in the emitted Intermediate Language (IL) code**.

Here `new List<int> { 1337 };` is an instruction that is run at **runtime**. The compiler cannot embed this `new List<int> { 1337 };` in the IL **without running the code to actually create the list**.

For more information: 
[How to stop C# from replacing const variable with their values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022779/how-to-stop-c-sharp-from-replacing-const-variable-with-their-values/21023404#21023404)