# C# Giving Up on const for use in non-static context

Tags: c#

I have the following readonly string in my C# class.

```
private readonly string someString= "I am a string.";
```

I feel the urge to convert this to a `const` because the information is available at compile time. However, I have it as `readonly` because I am using it in a non-static context.

Is this the right thing to do? Or am I having an issue with my code design?

Comment: This ticket may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly

Comment: What makes you think that using a `const` in a non-static context is wrong?

Comment: You have declared it as private, so it will be used only within the class you write. So keeping it as `const` is enough. Even `const` can be used in non-static context.

Comment: I am trying to use the variable in a non-static method and it is complaining to me that it cannot.

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use that string from a non-static method. If you're getting a compiler error, *give us the compiler error*, otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just figured out why. I was referring to the variable as `this.someString`. The error went away after I switched to `MyClass.someString`.

Comment: By the way, can anyone care to explain what difference this makes?

Comment: Constants are, in effect, always static, and as such aren't part of any instance. Therefore, you address them through the class and not through an instance. If you think about it, it doesn't make sense for constants to be instance-based - this.someString implies "the value of someString that belongs to this instance", which is misleading because it's exactly the same someString that all other instances have access to as well.