# Const string referencing another const string - how to avoid DRY without readonly

Tags: c#

```
public static class Abc
{
    public const string Placeholder = "{$content}";
    public const string Pattern = $"<div class=\"embed-responsive\">{Placeholder}</div>";
}
```

How to correctly solve this to avoid breaching DRY (Dont repeat yourself)? I know I can use static readonly, but then it is a bit of a different thing (even though it works..). I think there should be better way? Or is there really not?

Comment: whats wrong with `static readonly`?

Comment: @Dr.Fre: For explanation on differences between const and readonly please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you cannot call a method to initialize a constant value, it is allowed to use operators. If you need to create a constant that contains another constant value, use the plus operator to concatenate string values.

```
public static class Abc
{
    public const string Placeholder = "{$content}";
    public const string Pattern = "<div class=\"embed-responsive\">" + Placeholder + "</div>";
}
```