# What is the real difference between a static member and a constant in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#,and now i'm trying to understand static members and constants.Which is the best way to declare a constant?
This way?

```
class Myclass
{
    public const double G=9.8;
}
```

Or

```
   class Myclass
    {
        private static double G{get;set;}
        static MyClass()
        {
            G=9.8;
        }
    }
```

I've asked this question because,with the 2 ways i access the membre with the same code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Myclass.G);
```

Comment: You can assign a static property. You cannot do that with a const.

Comment: Your question is confusing; `static` and `const` have very little in common, except that a `const` is a `static`. Maybe you meant to ask about the [difference between `const` and `static readonly`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55984/767890)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

Answer (score 1):

**constant**:

> Constant fields are defined at the time of declaration in the code
>   snippet, because once they are defined they can't be modified. By
>   default a constant is static, so you can't define them static from
>   your side.
>
> It is also mandatory to assign a value to them at the time of
>   declaration otherwise it will give an error during compilation of the
>   program snippet. That's why it is also called a compile-time constant.

**Explanation:**

Consider ff. code:

```
void Sum(int j)  
{  
  const int i = 9, k = 2;  
  const int A = i + k;  
}
```

This will produce a result of 11, without showing any error since we already declared it at the initial point of declaration.

But how about:

```
void Sum(int j)  
{  
   const int i = 9, k = 2;  
  //const int A = i + k;  
   Const int B = i + j;  
}
```

This code snippet will take you toward a compile-time error, because there is no initialization, since it's evaluated at run time.

**Points to Remember**

- Compile-time constant
- Can't be declared static
- Can't be modified or changed
- Can be of any type of Access Modifier
- Local scope
- Needs to get initialized
- Declared at the time of declaration

---

**Static**

> The `static` keyword is used to declare a static member. If we are
>   declare a class as a static class then in this case all the class
>   members must be static too. The static keyword can be used effectively
>   with classes, fields, operators, events, methods and so on
>   effectively.

Consider ff. code:

```
class ReadOnly  
{  
    static int i = 11;  
    public static void disp()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }  
}
```

**Explanation:**

This code will show no error and produce a result (11), since we declared its value to be static at the time of declaration. So we can access it depending on our use in the program.

But how about this:

```
class ReadOnly  
{  
    int i = 9;  
    public static void disp()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(i);  
    }  
}
```

This snippet above will show an error, because we didn't declare a value for the static and we are trying to access it within a method. We can't do that.

**Points to Remember:**

- Can't be used with indexers
- Works with constructors too
- By default it is private
- Can be parameterized or public too
- If its applied to a class then all the class members need to be static

You can read more about above explanation here: [constant vs readonly vs static](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/constant-vs-readonly-vs-static-keywords-in-C-Sharp/)

Additional note for `static` methods.

Consider ff. code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public string SomeMethod() {
      return "Hello, World.";
    }
}
```

When you want to Access `SomeMethod` of `SomeClass`, you need to instantiate `SomeClass` first:

```
var some = new SomeClass();
string result = some.SomeClass(); //this will set result as "Hello, World."
```

Compared to a static method:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static string SomeMethod() {
      return "Hello, World.";
    }
}
```

When accessing `SomeMethod`, you don't need to instantiate `SomeClass`. You can access it directly by:

```
string result = SomeClass.SomeMethod(); //this will give "Hello, World."
```

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the best way to declare a constant?

Its not the best, its the *only way*: `const double G = 9.8;`.

> Or (...) `static double G { get; set; }`

Thats not a constant! Constant means *constant*: `1` is a constant, `'c'`is a constant, `PI` is a constant... they represent values that *don't change*, ***ever!***. Your second implementation of `G` can change, therefore its not a constant.

Also, its important you notice that constants are *known at compile time*, there is no evaluation needed at runtime.

This is the reason why any reference type `const` (expect `string` which has specific compiler support through string *literals*) can only be initialized to `null`, any other option would need to be evaluated at runtime.

Its also the reason why only a finite set of value types can be declared as `const` too. All of them are existing types in the framework and.. surprise, surprise, they all have compiler *literal* constant support: `1`, `'c'`, `9.8` or `0.25M` but not `01/01/2017` (how else would the compiler know the values before runtime?).

> Another interesting question you didn't make is: what about `static readonly`?

You can think of `static readonly` as "the poor man's" `const`. Its often used to circumvent the limitations `const` offers concerning what types and initializing values are allowed.

It is *almost* the same as a constant, but there are a few important and decisive differences:

1. It *can* change; although it is `readonly`, you can change it's value inside the static constructor of the declaring type. `const` can never change after initialized.
2. It is evaluated at *runtime*, not compile time as a true `const`.
3. Any type can be declared as a `static readonly` and initialized to any valid value as you would do with any regular field.

As a nittpicking side note, you shouldn't make `G` a constant ;). It changes, and quite a bit. `G` in Ecuador is different from `G` in the North Pole.

Answer (score 0):

> const variables are assigned values at time of definition.

They are available at compile time. You can even use a compile time evaluate-able expression at compile time. But once a value has been assigned to a const variable, it cannot be changed at any other time.

> Using static field means the value will remain same for every user of the application, but this value can be changed by code in any of the classes, and it will change for every user of the application.

Do not use static for constants, use const only. const are by default static, and you cannot use static keyword with it.

Check this

```
void Main()
{
 // You will not be able to change value for const variable.
 Console.WriteLine(Myclass.G);

  // You will be able to change value for static variable, 
 // and this change will impact all users of the application.
 //  For every user, this field will store value of 10 now. 
 // That will not be required or desired code behavior.
 Myclass1.G = 10;
 Console.WriteLine(Myclass1.G);
}

// Normal class with const field 
class Myclass
{
    public const double G=9.8;
}

 //static class with static constructor
 static class Myclass1
    {
        public static double G{get;set;}
        static Myclass1()
        {
            G=9.8;
        }
    }
```

[Read More](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/csharp/difference-between-constant-and-readonly-and-static)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are talking about two different things, and this is their definition from MSDN:

1- **static modifier**: To declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object. The static modifier can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators, events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers, finalizers, or types other than classes.

2- **const keyword**: To declare a constant field or a constant local. Constant fields and locals aren't variables and may not be modified. Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference. Don’t create a constant to represent information that you expect to change at any time.

So a static member is defined for a Class (for all its instances, and that's why you can access it directly from the name of the Class) but can be modified. a const field of class can not be modified.