# Static pre-defined instances of a class

Tags: c#, object, static, constants, instance

I hope not to make a duplicate but I didn't find what I'm searching for.

I'm developing a Asp.Net MVC website with a personal area where you can buy a subscription for the application.  I have 3 plans for subscription, they are all objects of the same class.

I'm thinking if is possible to create these 3 objects as constants with different values and put them in a static class.
What is the best way to do this?

I'd like to retrieve the subscription object with something like `Subscriptions.ONE_MONTH` or `Subscriptions.SIX_MONTHS`.

Comment: You basically just described how to do it, what is the problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: So did you create a static class with three constants? Did it work? You also might consider using an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).

Comment: If you want any help you will have to let us know what you actually need help with.

Comment: I don't know if I explained correctly.
I have a Subscription class and I need to have 3 instances of this class with different values but without creating an empty instance and setting every field, just three instances of this class with pre-defined values..

Comment: Do you want other instances of the subscription class to be created?  Or only ever the 3 types you defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is to have the three plans as `public static` getter-only properties of the static class. You can create the instances either inline, or in the static constructor of the class.

```
public static PlanA { get; } = new Plan(...);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few possible ways to do this. You could create a static class with public fields or properties:

```
public static class Subscriptions
{
    public static whateverType OPTION_1 = whateverValue;
    public static whateverType OPTION_2 = whateverValue;
    public static whateverType OPTION_3 = whateverValue;
}

public static class Subscriptions
{
    public static whateverType OPTION_1 => whateverValue;
    public static whateverType OPTION_2 => whateverValue;
    public static whateverType OPTION_3 => whateverValue;
}
```

or if the values are of a basic type an enum:

```
public enum Subscriptions
{
   Option_1,
   Option_2,
   Option_3 
}
```

If you want to use an enum with the possibility of having more than one value you can use the Flags attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum Subscriptions
{
   Option_1 = 1,
   Option_2 = 2,
   Option_3 = 4
}
```

One thing you should probably avoid is having public constant values in a non static class (for the reasons see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)):

```
public class Subscriptions
{
    public const whateverType OPTION_1 = whateverValue;
    public const whateverType OPTION_2 = whateverValue;
    public const whateverType OPTION_3 = whateverValue;
}
```