# C#, how to use constant depends on running env (dev/prod)

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, constants, resources

Looking for the best practice in c# program for using constant  depends on  running env (dev/prod)

I used const values but the problem is when switching environment.

Looking for a good DP/OOP idea.

Comment: Control it with compile variables and `#if / #endif` maybe?

Comment: I would argue that those should not be constants but settings/configuration.

Comment: You should not use const for values that can change.
Even they just change at the beginning for your program.
I would agree with @GuruStron

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to create separate `Config` files for different environments.
Let's say you have `Config.dev.json` and `Config.prod.json` files.
Both files contain the same data structure, but with different values for each environment.
You could use the `appsettings.json` file as an example.
Then you can use the `Config` file as a source of your constants values.

Comment: and how would you do the switch? So how do you decide which file to use?

Comment: You can have different launch settings profiles and within each profile, you can set the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" or "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production". So in the release profile you would use appsettings.Production.Json

And the corresponding appsettings.{env}.json will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what kind of constant you mean.
Within C# there are different kinds of constants/readonly values.

- Compile time constant (E.G. `const int Two = 2`)
- Runtime constant

  - fields (E.G. `readonly int Two = 2`)
  - properties (E.G. `int Two { get; } = 2` or `int Two => 2`)

All of these values can be regarded as 'constant' as they can't change value during runtime. More info here: [What is the difference between const and readonly in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly-in-c)

Usually when specifying environment-specific values, this is done via a configuration file.
In newer .Net (core) versions, you can use `appsettings.json`. This provides the option to add `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`, which can contain the respective values.
When using the default configuration provider of .net core, the system will choose the appsettings file corresponding to your `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment`.

When you're not able to use appsettings files for some reason, you can also use the HostEnvironment to make a switch:

```cs
private IHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

int Two => _hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? 3 : 2;
// or
int Two => _hostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development") ? 3 : 2;
```

More info on environments and appsettings here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

If you actually do require a compile time constant, your only option is to use pragma's. For example:

```cs
#if DEBUG
const int Two = 3;
#else
const int Two = 2;
#endif
```

When doing so, you need to compile the application with configuration 'Debug' for your Development application and with configuration 'Release' for your production application.

More info on pragma's (preprocessor directives) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives